# Connect to SQL Server from IIS (ASP.Net Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I spend hours trying multiple combinations to connect my asp.net core site hosted on an IIS Server to a remote SQL Server using just the SQL user and password without exit. This is my connection string in appsettings.json:

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Booking": "Server=SQLServerName;Database=Booking;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;"
  }
```

- I have tried to set Integrated security = false and Trusted connection = false
- I changed the property Identity in the App pool to LocalSystem, although _I have tried all the options.
- I can connect to the database from my computer to SQLManager without any issue.
- In my events viewer, I see the next error: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\NAMEOFTHESERVER$'.
- SQL Server 2016 in the database server, windows server 2016 in the webserver.
- I use windows authentication for user authentication, but I need to use a simple user and password to connect to the db.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\NAMEOFTHESERVER$'.

This means that the connection string you show is not being used, because this username belongs to `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`. So there's another configuration file being used, for example `appsettings.development.json`, which uses `Integrated Security=True`, using the application pool's identity.

Change the environment in your web.config to production, so the `appsettings.development.json` is not used:

```
<system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore ...>
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you miss set permissions in IIS if you have set permissions for sql db for a specific user.

[image]

Comment: I use windows authentication for users, but the connection to the database has to be using this user and password, nothing else.

Comment: It not related even You use windows authentication for SQL server. But I see it is not your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a connection string with SQL Server Authentication (a User ID and Password present in the connection string) and you’re getting the error referenced in this thread (`Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'`), be sure to remove the `OnConfiguring` method containing the original connection string you used to generate your model classes from your database context class (if you used entity framework’s database first approach).  In my case, I used integrated security to scaffold (https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx#google_vignette) the database model POCOs, but I later then changed the connection string in `appsettings.json` to use SQL Server Authentication.

It appeared that the `appsettings.json` connection string entries were being ignored, which they were because my `dbContext.cs` class still had the `OnConfiguring` method using the connection string I used to generate the model (the integrated security value).

Basically, no matter how you’re connecting to your database, make sure your database context class does not have an `OnConfiguring` method using a connection string that will override what is in the `appsettings.json` or `web.config` files!